# "Was going to" translation

Tags: перевод

How do you express the phrase "was going to" as in "I forget what I was going to say"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A usual interpretation  is **собирался** (to do something ).But we also use **хотел** in this case meaning intention.

> I forget what I was going to say--Я забываю,что собирался (хотел) сказать.

Since *forget* is often used instead of *forgot* or *have forgotten*(though some people consider it incorrect) we'd better say

> Я **забыл**, что хотел сказать.

Comment: Even though in English you can say "I forget..." when you actually mean "I forgot...", in Russian the former form has a different meaning, so you better use the latter: "я забыл что хотел сказать".

Comment: There's no context. Can't you say "I (sometimes) forget what I was going to say"?

Comment: Yes there is. Why else would the author mention the "as in" part? Also check [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8819/forgot-vs-forget/8823) out.

Comment: Thank you, it's very interesting. But they say it's incorrect to use pres.simple for past and they don't exclude a repetitive meaning.  I am going to edit my answer.

Comment: What is the difference between using собираться and собраться (besides being imperfective/perfective)?

Comment: Aspect only, imperf/perf.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on style, you can use:

- Собираться
- Хотеть
- Намереваться
- Думать
- Замышлять
- Планировать
- Задумывать
- Вознамериваться

...and many more! I assume you are already familiar with putting those verbs in a needed form.

Good luck!